# I need to remove page title of home page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, home-page, page-title

I have tried to change homepage title from admin and xml but nothing take effect.Can i change it from Database or any other way to change.

Comment: are you using cms page for home page ?

Comment: Disabling the H1 title in Magento 2 is a fairly simple process. You first need to override the Magento blank or luma theme and navigate to this folder:

app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout

Comment: Of course you’ll need to replace <vendor> and <theme> with your own values. Inside the folder you need to create or edit the file cms_index_index.xml.

The content of the file should be:


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSche$
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>

Comment: also please clear cache and reindex your site

Comment: Yes Rahul Singh there is CMS page.But that title not working

Answer (score 2):

**-------- Magento 2 - remove home page title -----------**

You can add reference block in your cms_index_index.xml

> `<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" display="false"/>`

Using **"true & false"** you can display you page title based on your requirements